# I want to Run a batch file to install my build -which makes uses of mstest to do Ui automation. How can i integrate this to jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, ui-automation, cicd

I have implemented jenkins pipeline, In where my code is build locally - i wanted to add a addtional stage of testing , I use ui-automation with the help of *specflow and mstest* to install my build, i tried running the **batch file**- but it fails as install window doesn't come up.
this is my code

```
  stage('Installation') {
            steps {
                bat 'call C:\\Smoketest\\TypicalInstall.bat'
            }
        }
```

how can i integrate this to my jenkin pipeline ?

Comment: Is this something with a UI?

Comment: yeah it is to do with UI